# Object Expected at onLoad

Tags: javascript, onload, dynamics-crm-4

I have an own entity called PurchaseOrder. For this entity I have designed a javascript for the onload method which also should work perfectly fine.

My problem now is that when I want to create a new PurchaseOrder an empty form is coming up as expected but with this error message:

```
There was an error with the fields customized event
Field: window
Event: onload
Error: Object expected
```

If I save this PurchaseOrder and then try to open it again there is no error message.

The big problem is that this error message also shows up if I disable the customized onload script or remove my code from the onload event. 
There is also no error message if I try to open the preview of this entity.

I don't want to post any code since this script has about 1000 lines of code and either I'm to stupid or I just can't use the debugger of the IE so I also can't post the snippet where the error occurs.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Apart from using the IE debugger I'm not sure what to suggest here. Have you tried sticking in a load of alert('hello') messages to debug?

Comment: No I haven't. But I tried it now and with nothing in the custom onload but the alert and the error still pops up. Could this mean that the onload of the entity itself isn't working? Can such things happen with custom entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit me... Hit me really hard...

For days I was struggling with this and you know what the solution was? Publish the entity and refresh the page. Seems like I was testing the whole time the old wrong solution...

-.-

Anyways, thanks James for trying to help but with this level of stupidity of mine you can't be smart enough to help me here ^^

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion :)